# Send multiple http responses to a single http request in netty

Tags: http, netty, server-sent-events

I want to stream multiple http responses for a single request from a netty server.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one *final* HTTP response per request, but you can send multiple 1xx responses (with no payload) before sending the final one.

Comment: I want to send multiple payloads like it is done in Server Sent Events.

Comment: That's not possible. You can stream the payload though, using chunked encoding.